# sqlite disk i/o error when performing SELECT statement

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, adobe

i had the follwing sql statement;

```
SELECT customer_name, cst_id 
FROM master_customer 
ORDER BY cst_id DESC;

*** ERROR *** : Error #3128: Disk I/O error occurred.
```

i checked the db access permissions : ok

i did integrity check : ok

1. whats the cause of this?
2. what are the possible solutions?

NOTE: i dont have any antivirus program that would hold my db when performing scans.

Comment: @jnovack actually, i had visited that post but with no answer...